# How to I make sure that curl doesn't fail a script?

Tags: bash, curl

How do I make sure curl errors doesn't fail a script? I want to send all errors from curl to Dev null so that it doesn't fail a script and the script keeps going

What's the proper curl command to do that.

I tried curl --fail http://...

For curl to fail silently

Comment: `--fail` *causes* `curl` to exit with a nonzero status -- it's for use when you *intend* your script to fail if the `curl` command does (or at least to be able to detect that `curl` failed; as an example of its purpose, `if curl --fail ...` will decide whether to follow the `then` or `else` branches based on whether the HTTP call succeeded, with a server-side error such as a 502 counted as a failure).

Comment: If `curl` is causing your script to exit, you appear to have the `-e` option set via something like `set -e`; remove that from your script. Redirecting error messages to /dev/null doesn't affect how your script runs; it only suppress any error messages that `curl` produces on an error.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried:

```
curl http://.../ || true
```

And if you want to hide any error output, have you tried:

```
curl http://.../ 2>/dev/null || true
```

(Note: Untested.)

Comment: `||:` is the conventional shorthand for `|| true`, btw.

Comment: ...and you might suggest the `--silent` argument. Better to tell a program not to write anything at all than to have it waste its time writing to a file descriptor that's redirected to `/dev/null`. (Of course, doing both at once can make sense as a belt-and-suspenders approach...)